Why don't I see amd64 packages in ports.ubuntu.com?
I'm learning debian packages and by inspecting the official Ubuntu repository at "http://it.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ubuntu-ports/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/" I don't see .deb packages for amd64 architectures. There are .deb packages for arm64 but not for amd64 which is where most Ubuntu systems run on.
Are they somewhere else? Maybe in one of those zipped files?

PORTS refers to non-main architectures, ie. PPC64EL, S390X, AMD64, ARMHF etc... where the main AMD64 & i386 parckages are found in the ARCHIVE (http://archive.ubuntu.com/)

Packages are split into two archives

the main archive (http://archive.ubuntu.com/) for amd64, i386

the PORTS architectures, which include arm64, armhf, s390x, riscv64, ppc64el


You're question has you looking in the location for PORT architectures.

FYI:   In rare cases; a PORTS package (latest for a release) can be a different version to the (latest for the same release) of the main archive... so the architectures being listed in commands like rmadison is actually very useful.
